# Software RAID Issues with Missing Drive from Boot

Tags: linux, rhel, raid, mdadm

I have a 3-drive software raid1 (on RHEL 7) that I am trying to test the limits on. This system boots in legacy/mbr mode and does not support uefi. One of the problems I have encountered is; from a powered off state, if I remove a drive, the system will boot but just before you are prompted to log in, the system drops to an emergency shell. So that we are clear; the system gets past grub and starts x, then it drops after about 20 seconds of "thinking." (I also observed that /boot and /etc don't exist.)

I see that if I properly 'fail' the drive before rebooting, this isn't an issue. This only becomes and issue if the power is off and I remove a drive before powering on. (I see that this is a realistic scenario as, if I lose power and a drive becomes corrupt, then I would encounter this problem).

Is there a way to prevent the raid from failing to properly boot? Is it possible to have mdadm rebuild the raid1 so that the system can work in a degraded status (2 of 3 hard drives)?